# javascript inheritance and instance variables

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to understand how inheritance works in JS. Suppose we have a class:

```
Class = function () {
    this.A = 'A';
    this.B = 'B';
};
```

and we are trying to extend it

```
SubClass = function () {};
SubClass.prototype = new Class();
```

Do I understance correctly that after inheritance properties `A` and `B` are common for all instances of `SubClass`, since they belong to it's prototype? If yes, how can `Class` be extended so that `A` and `B` do not be part of prototype?

**UPD:** note that `Class` uses `A` and `B`, so I can't declare them in SubClass.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: _how can Class be extended so that A and B do not be part of prototype?_ What's the purpose of using prototypes then?

Comment: If you want to have in each instance of SubClass 'A' and 'B' just don't declare it in prototype, declare it in SubClass.

Comment: @Prodigy,`Class` uses `A` and `B`, so I can't declare them in SubClass.

Comment: @elclanrs,I'm not sure I'm using the right terminology. All I want is to make `A` and `B` be accessible and specific for each "instance" of `SubClass`.

Comment: What exactly do you need to inherit from `Class`? Javascript is very flexible so you are likely just need another, maybe non-prototypal way of extending your objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> All I want is to make A and B be accessible and specific for each
>   "instance"

The typical way of doing this is to pass parameters and assign them to properties. Then you can use `call` to reference the super class. In other words:

```
function Person( name, age ) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
}

function Student( name, age, grade ) {
  Person.call( this, name, age ); // call super-class with sub-class properties
  this.grade = grade;
}

Student.prototype = new Person();
Student.prototype.constructor = Student;

var roger = new Student( 'Roger', 18, 'A+' );
```

Comment: thank you! looks like you're proposing just what I need, the only question is: maybe there should be `Person.call( this, name, age );` instead of `Person.call( name, age );`

Comment: I have just confirmed that it should, indeed, be `Person.call(this, name, age)`.  The `this` reference is essential.

Answer (score 1):

You can use properties in parent class without defining:

```
Class = function () {
   this.sum = function() {
       return this.a+this.b;    
   }
};

SubClass = function () {
    this.a = 5;
    this.b = 6;
}; 

SubClass.prototype = new Class();

var z = new SubClass();
z.sum(); //11
```

Another way: Create function in prototype which creates your properties:

```
Class = function () {   
    this.makeAB = function() { //called with context of SubClass
        this.A = 'A';
        this.B = 'B';        
    }
};

SubClass = function () { this.makeAB() }; 
SubClass.prototype = new Class();

var z = new SubClass();
z.A = 'AAA';
z.B = 'BBB';

var z2 = new SubClass();

console.log(z)
console.log(z2)
```